# How to load another html/url in electron browser window( index. hml using html5 template)?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Sorry for the naivety in the question. explaining it here.
so i used this sample electron app from this repo:
https://github.com/crilleengvall/electron-tutorial-app

here he used html5 template to navigate within the browser window,
explained here: https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-app-navigation/

on the welcome page/section, i want to create a button, which loads another html file but in the section, not like filling up the whole browser window because i will still need the side bar panel for navigation.
somewhat like this:
[image]

also, is it possible to add a option in the menu where we can show/hide any new browser window created?

i would be obliged to give more details if i didnt make myself clear.

Comment: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view

Comment: What you had done?